# How to wait for an element to be defined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to do the equivalent of this in javascript:

```
while (typeof someObject == 'undefined') {
     sleep(10);  // 10ms
}
```

And I just can't quite figure out how to code this.

I have this:

```
function sleep(ms, callback, arg) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(arg);
    }, ms);
}

function waitForDef(elem) {
    if (typeof elem == 'undefined') {
        sleep(10, waitForDef, elem);
    }
}
```

But it's not clear to me how to use this from my code.

Comment: Wherever your code is defining `someObject`, you should also accept a callback function, which you invoke after you define the variable. You probably should just pass the value directly to the callback, instead of sharing state with a global variable as well.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for promises.

Comment: @meagar: exactly. you should use a callback function

Comment: This is usually a symptom of bad code design. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need to wait for this element to exist? Why doesn't it exist immediately? What is creating it? When it is being created? Why is it being created? What do you intend to do with it once it exists?

Comment: After my page is loaded I need to call a js function that will only exist some time after a table gets given a certain class. When I try to call that function from an onload function it fails most of the time because the table does not yet have the class. If I call that function from a setTimeout that waits 1 second it works 99% of the time. I'd like to just wait until the class gets put on the table and the function exists and then call it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have an interval running that keeps checking on the element:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // get elem
    if (typeof elem == 'undefined') return;
    clearInterval(interval);

    // the rest of the code
}, 10);
```

Comment: This looks like it will work perfectly for me. I've implemented it and so far so good. I still need to run it for a bit more to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: It was a bit tricky as it was not an element I was waiting for but a property. So I had to first wait for the element to exist and then wait for it to have the property. But your answer got me on the right road.

Comment: You should still be able to do one interval only. Did you end up with two?

Comment: No, just one. I first test for the element and then the property.